# How to use os.system() inside a python executable file?

Tags: python, shell, cmd, pyinstaller

I need to run this command `instagram-scraper "+ username +" --media-metadata --media-types none`
inside a python executable file as you see bellow is the code I'm using to do that and it's working fine when I run it like that `py test.py`, but after I turn it to an executable file using the PyInstaller command: `pyinstaller -F test.py`, **it doesn't work** and it doesn't return any error, the console disapears directly after execution.

```
import os

def getFollowers(username):
    os.system("instagram-scraper "+ username +" --media-metadata --media-types none")

getFollowers("oukebdane_med_anis")
```

Comment: 1. Your function does not return or prints anything. Thus you have no output. 2. The executable is not in the same folder, from where you are running the packaged python program.

Comment: Try manually starting a `cmd` console (command window), and then manually running the executable inside it. This will allow you to see any error messages. The most likely cause is that the `instagram-scraper` utility isn't in the current directory.

Comment: instagram-scraper is not a local directory, it's an outside package

Comment: https://github.com/arc298/instagram-scraper

Comment: You install `instagram-scraper` with `pip install instagram-scraper` in your Python environment **BUT** the Python environment used by `PyInstaller` does have the `instagram-scraper` executables...

Comment: Note that there are serious security issues with your code. What if someone tells it their username is `; rm -rf ~/*;`? It's much safer to stay away from `os.system` and instead use `subprocess.Popen` with the default `shell=False`.

Comment: dear Charles, tahnk you so much for your advice, it's a great remark

Comment: Try replacing the `instagram-scraper` with the full path to the program (I asked whether it was **in** the current directory, not whether it **was** one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle, I finally found a solution to the problem, according to the strategy suggested by Mr. @AKX, whom I thank very much.

```
import instagram_scraper as isc

def getFollowers(username): 
    scraper = isc.InstagramScraper(usernames=[username], media_metadata=True, media_types=['none'])
    scraper.scrape()

getFollowers("oukebdane_med_anis")
```

> NOTE: I tried to edit his answer to adapted to the correct solution but it says 'Suggested edit queue is full'

Answer (score 2):

There's no way PyInstaller can understand `os.system("instagram-scraper ...")` should also bundle up that instagram-scraper library. You'll need to use it without `os.system()` for PyInstaller to be able to follow references; something like

```
import instagram_scraper as isc

def getFollowers(username):
    scraper = isc.InstagramScraper(username=username, media_metadata=True, media_types=[])
    scraper.authenticate_as_guest()
    scraper.scrape()
```

might work for you...

Comment: I liked the way you tried to solve the problem but after trying your code I didn't get anything (no errors and no outputs)...try it please

Comment: I don't much care for trying to circumvent Instagram's terms of use, so I won't. There might be something I'm missing, but you can peek at the library's source to figure out what.

Comment: I did it many times I dive as mush as I can but I can't see the lost piece...Help me please